# Cleveland Cavaliers championship bonus

Tags: basketball, nba

Do the Cavs players get some sort of bonus compensation from the team and / or the NBA?
What about the coaching staff and owners?

If so, do you know how much this bonus is?

As a data point, way back, in the 1990s when the Knicks made it to the eastern conference finals (John Starks, Patrick Ewing, Charles Oakley and others) each player got around 100k bonus, which was reported by the local news.

Answer (score 3):

**The NBA** sets aside a playoff’s pool of **money as a bonus to teams for their performance**.

Last year that figure was at $13 million with a maximum of $8 million that can go to any team. This year the prize money seems confirmed. If you were to divide that figure equally to all players in the team that would equate to each player receiving a maximum over $500,000.

[This is the source](http://www.fxnewscall.com/nba-finals-2016-cleveland-cavaliers-new-champions-how-much-did-they-get/1941839/)

If the players divide the prize money in percentage of thier wage the bonus can be very different and [here](http://moneynation.com/how-much-money-players-make-win-nba-finals/) you can find a simulation on Warriors players (made before the end of the season)

Individual players may then have economic advantages with successive contracts, but in this case it is not about bonuses.